# Limitations using Facebook Unity Integration on WebPlayer

Tags: html, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

we are using Facebook's **Unity SDK on the Facebook Web Platform** (using Unity WebPlayer).
We went for the **non-html approach** so we only provide the .unity3d file url. (Unity Integration button is active)

Using this method we have this three problems:

1) we find **no way to customize the Unity loading screen**. This method and this method only work using old html integration way.

2) on **Windows platforms**, **any Facebook floating div**, such as chat windows or search dialog result, **make the game to be invisible**. (if fact facebook javascript sent the game canvas to -10000 x-position)

3) we **can't use a custom html tiled background image**. We might change the background after Unity is loaded but the transition doesn't look good

My questions are:

- Is is possible to solve them and still using Unity Integration method?
- Do you suggest us to go for the old html integration method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. We are working to resolve this soon.
2. Unfortunately for certain browsers, Unity will always draw on top of everything.  That means when chat windows pop up they would appear under the game.  We try to keep the game around if this isn't the case.
3. Does `Application.ExternalEval()` with JS not work for you?

The benefits you get from using the Unity Integration is that:

- the dialogs will appear in game, so your players won't be kicked out of fullscreen if they are there.
- cross platform would be easier, as you don't have to integrate a different SDK if you also export to Android and iOS
- don't have to manage the web page on canvas

Unless you want more DOM control directly through JS/HTML before the game loads, it's probably better to stick with the Unity Integration.

I hope that helps your decision making.